# vector<double> areas(contour.size()) in c#? mass of center, area. Particle Analyze

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

Hello i want to analyze Particles with EmguCV. I am using it obviously because i use C#. I found some Code which seems to be perfect for me purpose but it is written in C++, so i am trying to get it run in C#. Now i am stuck because i don´t find something similiar to this code which works in c#

Also i want to tell that i am a rookie programmer and c# is also new for me

THIS IS THE CODE in C++

```
Mat frame = imread("particles.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

threshold(frame, frame, 127, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours(frame, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

vector<double> areas(contours.size());

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    areas[i] = contourArea(contours[i]);

vector<Point2d> mass_centres(contours.size());

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    const Moments mu = moments(contours[i], false);
    mass_centres[i] = Point2d(mu.m10 / mu.m00, mu.m01 / mu.m00);
}

cout << "Num particles: " << contours.size() << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    cout << "area " << (i + 1) << ": " << areas[i] << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    cout << "centre " << (i + 1) << ": " << mass_centres[i].x << " " << mass_centres[i].y << endl;

return 0;
```

}

THAT IS WHAT I HAVE WRITTEN SO FAR IN C#

```
        Mat frame = CvInvoke.Imread(file2, ImreadModes.Grayscale);

        CvInvoke.Threshold(frame, frame, 127, 255, ThresholdType.Binary);

        Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint();

        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

        CvInvoke.FindContours(frame, contours, hierarchy, RetrType.Tree, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
```

NOW I AM STUCK HERE AND I DON´t NOW ALTERNATIVE TO THIS CODE:

```
vector<double> areas(contours.size());

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    areas[i] = contourArea(contours[i]);

vector<Point2d> mass_centres(contours.size());

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    const Moments mu = moments(contours[i], false);
    mass_centres[i] = Point2d(mu.m10 / mu.m00, mu.m01 / mu.m00);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my Problem with the following Code.

```
        double[] area = new double[contours.Size];

        for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
        {
            area[i] = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours[i]);
        }


        double[] mass_centerX = new double[contours.Size];
        double[] mass_centerY = new double[contours.Size];


        for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
        {
            Moments mu = CvInvoke.Moments(contours[i], false);

            mass_centerX[i] = mu.M10 / mu.M00;
            mass_centerY[i] = mu.M01 / mu.M00;

            mass_centerX[i] = Math.Round(mass_centerX[i], 2);
            mass_centerY[i] = Math.Round(mass_centerY[i], 2);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions which you are looking for are [CvInvoke.ContourArea](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.2.0/document/html/6ef05086-8aa7-3f1b-a27f-42594e776465.htm) and [CvInvoke.Moments](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.2.0/document/html/b251a843-286b-39f1-7de7-17ee8750aa30.htm).

The code can then be written as follows:

```
List<double> areas = new List<double>();
foreach(Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfPoint contour in contours)
{
    areas.Add(Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.ContourArea(contour));
} 

VectorOfPoint mass_centers = new VectorOfPoint();
foreach(Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfPoint contour in contours)
{
    Emgu.CV.Structure.MCVMoments mu = Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.Moments(contour); 
    mass_centers.Push(Emgu.CV.Point2D<double>(mu.M10 / mu.M00, mu.M01 / mu.M00));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using EmguCV Version 4, so if i copy/paste your Code the compiler finds errors. The first one is here: ...contour in contours... //foreach can not be used for "VectorofVectorofPoints" the 2nd is that it can not recognize Emgu.CV.Point2D